# Изменить css --before-border-left jquery

Tags: html, css, jquery

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var color = $(this).val();
  $('#funnel_id_41').css('background', color);
  $('#funnel_id_41').css('--before-border-left', '15px solid'+color);
});
```

```css
.funnel_item {
    width: auto;
    height: 30px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-right: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.funnel_item:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 15px solid white;
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}
.funnel_item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: var(--before-border-left, black);
    border-top: 15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 15px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="funnel_item" id="funnel_id_41" style="background: #003c70;--before-border-left: 15px solid #003c70;">
</div>
<input type="color">
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу с помощью jquery изменить `--before-border-left`

Comment: @Sevastopol' фигура css

Comment: @Sevastopol' обновил код, посмотрите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ну как бы код в вопросе работает, стрелка цвет меняет. В чём собственно поблема?

Comment: @Qwertiy не могу понять в чем причина, у меня аналогичный код, а before меняться не хочет.

Comment: Судя по примеру, проблема явно не в этом участке кода.

Comment: @Vector, попробуйте "инициализировать переменную" `--before-border-left` в родителе, а не в псевдо-элементе.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 что вы имеете ввиду? В before она лишь вызвана.

Comment: @Vector, имею ввиду использовать следующий подход `.el {--var: #000;} .el::before {color: var(--var); }`. А вообще, скорее всего, ошибка в том, что у вас нет пробела между `'15px solid'+color` после `solid`

Answer (score 1):

Через `.css` всё работает:

```js
setInterval(() => {
  $("html").css(
    "--bg",
    "#" + (Math.random() * 0x1000000 | 0x1000000).toString(16).slice(1)
  )
}, 500);
```

```css
html {
  --bg: silver;
}

body {
  background: var(--bg);
  transition: background-color 500ms linear;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```